# Rscript からのパッケージ読み込み

Tags: r, rscript

Windows　にて RGui からあるパッケージをインストールし， `library(パッケージ名)` とすると読み込まれるのですが，同じパッケージを Rscript から読み込もうとすると存在しないと言われます． Rscript でも追加パッケージを認識させるにはどうすれば良いですか?

Answer (score 1):

Rscriptのマニュアルに説明がございました。
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html

一部抜粋致します。

> Additional options accepted (before file or args) are
>
> --default-packages=list
>   where list is a comma-separated list of package names or NULL. Sets the environment variable R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES which determines the packages loaded on startup. The default for Rscript omits methods as it takes about 60% of the startup time.

要約すれば、

- 読み込みたいRファイルや引数の前にオプションをつけること
- 起動時に環境変数R_DEFAULT_PACKAGESに設定してロードする。。らしい。
- Rscriptで起動した場合、デフォルトの(Rguiで起動するような場合と比較して？注）メソッドの60%が省略される。。らしい。

  `Rscript --default-packages=util hoge.r`

みたいな実行方法で良いはず。